# findViewById returns null when moved files to Android library

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-library

In my `Intellij` IDE I have 2 Android modules: A, which is a library (used as a `jar`), and B, a normal android module that has dependency on A.

In project A i have `SomeActivity.java`, some_`layout.xml` (and a `VideoView` with `id`: some_view in it).
When earlier i had these modules merged into one, there was no problem with following logic:

```
public class SomeActivity extends RoboActivity
{
    VideoView view;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
        view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.some_view);
    }
    ...
}
```

but now `findViewById` returns null.

Note that project B does not override `some_layout.xml`

I use `guice3` with `roboguice 2.0` and injecting the views ends with `NullPointerException`.
The situation was the same with `guice2` and `roboguice 1.1.2`
Injecting by tag does the same thing.

Why does `findViewById` return `null` when i moved the files to external library module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android still having no support for export projects / libraries with resources to jars.

The only solution is to use it as project and check on Android Project Properties the box "is library" and add it to others projects (is the Android Project Properties) you are going to use.